# Increase uniform value in SKShader

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, shader

On a SpriteKit-Node, I run a fragment shader (SKShader) to show an animation (`canvasNode.fillShader = shader`).

At some point, I want to increase one of the uniform parameters (`transitionProgress`, between 0 and 1), to change the animation stage.

Currently, I just set it from 0 to 1.

```
shader.uniforms = [
    SKUniform(name: "u_transitionProgress", float: 1)
]
```

However, I would rather have a transition (like a linear increase, 0, 0.001, 0.002, ... , 0.999, 1) to have a smooth transition between these values.

Since I cannot store any values in the shader that I could increase at every execution, what is the best approach to achieve that effect? (or is the only way to execute the lines above again and again with slightly increase values?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `SKShader` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshader) says your shader receives this uniform:

> float u_time; | Uniform | The elapsed time in the simulation.

So use that to drive the animation.

The elapsed time is passed to the `SKScene`'s `update` method. Pass that to the shader in a uniform named `u_transitionStartTime`. Then you can calculate the transition progress using `u_time` and `u_transitionStartTime` (and, if necessary, another uniform for the transition end time or the transition duration).

Comment: It sounds like `update:` receives `CACurrentMediaTime()` rather than the time since the start of the simulation (whatever that is). On the first call to `update:`, you should save the time. Then in subsequent calls, you can subtract off that first time to get the “elapsed time in the simulation”.